my proble is about button when clicked on it it didnot run that show new menu
i make code js for icon beager in header so i due to when user click on it show new bakground-color that in it is ul ect
this code js i think my problem is in js
let bgc_menu_header = document.querySelector(".bgc_menu_header")
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-beager-icon")
let menuBtnicon = document.querySelector(".btn-beager-icon img")

bgc_menu_header.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if (menuBtnicon.classList.contains("menu_header")){
    bgc_menu_header.style.left = "0";
    menuBtnicon.classList="menu_header"
   } else{
        bgc_menu_header.style.left = "-299px";
    menuBtnicon.classList="menu_header"
   }
})


Why don't you just hide bgc_menu_header instead of adding offset of 299px?

Also you do not change the class. Don't you mean menuBtnicon.classList.toggle("menu_header") and why no add and remove a class that positions the icon?

i do not lrean js i got this cod from a person  so i only puted in my codes till it run

Please visit [ask] and also please use google translate since it is really hard to understand what you write

Please also [edit] your question to include all relevant code, such as html and css.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.
